# What's the lightest possible black hole?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, hawking-radiation

Is there, theoretically, a lower bound on the mass of a [black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole)? Or could you have a black hole that weights the same as an electron for example?

Comment: Did you check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_black_hole)?

Answer (score 4):

We don’t know.

Dimensional analysis suggests a black hole should finish its Hawking evaporation somewhere around the Planck mass.  But without a theory of quantum gravity, we don’t know whether there is some prefactor like $\frac12$ or $\frac{2^{10}}{5^4}$ out front. It could also be that the gravitational constant $G$ is different at short distances, so that our prediction of the Planck mass is wrong.